# Efficient algorithm in t-sql to mimic int.ToString("D4");

Tags: c#, t-sql, number-formatting

```
int i=99;
string s=i.ToString("D4");
//s=="0099"
```

Please advice on efficient implementation of preceding zeroes of numbers in textual format.

Comment: Not that it cannot be done, but are you sure that you must be formatting data in the database?  SQL Server is optimized to manage data, not format it.

Comment: This is one of rare cases when I move logic from my domain into db, since doing it in my domain will require a ado.net transaction and several db reqests to correctly generate the number. Sacrificing purity for performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

usually i do sth like:

```
RIGHT('0000' + [col], 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the funcion defined below

select dbo.fsPadLeft(@i,'0',4)

or inline statement 
Select  replicate(x,4-Len(x))+x from y

```
Create Function [dbo].[fsPadLeft](@var varchar(200),@padChar char(1)='0',@len int)
returns varchar(300)
as
Begin

return replicate(@PadChar,@len-Len(@var))+@var

end
```